# How do I avoid binding to 2 datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

My application looks like the following

[image]

The black is my MainWindow, the red is a tab control and the yellow is a UserControl.

The UserControl has many Dependency Properties defined and they bind to the DataContext (Which is set in the MainWindow's code behind, using `this.DataContext = this`).

To bind my UserControl to the same DataContext as my MainWindow, in my UserControl xaml I have the following

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=Window}}"
```

This works great, and when I interact with my UserControl, due to the two way binding, it updates the Properties of my MainWindow, which in turn updates my TabControl!

The issue is, my UserControl now has some extra functionality and as such, needs to bind to the UserControl's code behind (such as values for the GUI).

This is where I'm stuck. I can't bind from my UserControl to my code behind because I've already created a DataContext.

I know I could use the WinForms approach, and name each control with x:Name="MyControl" like

```
MyControl.Text = "This value";
```

or

```
MyControl.DataContext = this;
```

Yeuk I think!!

My question is, is this the only way to go, or can I still use binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need to manually set `DataContext` on UserControl. `DataContext` is an ***inheritable property so it will inherit DataContext from its parent unless you have explicitly  set it***.

Get rid of `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=Window}}"` from your UserControl.

---

And now, in case you want to bind to code behind for some controls in your UserControl, you can bind using `RelativeSource` or can set `DataContext` on control:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```

If controls can be clubbed together under one panel, set DataContext on parent panel say Grid and child controls will inherit from it:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType=UserControl}}">
   ..Child Controls here will inherit DataContext
</Grid>
```

---

And to answer your question:

> MyControl.DataContext = this; <-- Is this possible

Yes, it is possible like i mentioned above.

Comment: I know it is inherited - you've told me this before, yet I still insist in putting it in!! Sigh... one day I will learn!! You fixed it again for me! Thank you.

Comment: Oh did i? It's coming back to you in circle i guess.. :) You're welcome Dave..!! Have a great day.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use another `RelativeSource Binding` as you have for the `MainWindow` properties... to access the properties defined in the `UserControl`, try the following XAML in your `UserControl`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding UserControlProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl}}}" />
```

Obviously, you'll need to update `YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl` to a valid XML Namespace and control type to get this to work.

---

I'm *not* saying either that you should set the `DataContext` anywhere, or change any properties. This is a `RelativeSource Binding`... you do *not* need to set any `DataContext` to make it work. I thought you would have known that seeing as you're already using one. Just try the example out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. So, this means, my UserControl will bind to it's own DataContext (in this case the code behind), and I use the RelativeSource for each control in the UserControl which needs to bind to the MainWindow's DataContext? My MainWindow only has this.DataContext = this;